# How to capture signature image without any background in android?

Tags: android, canvas, background, signature

I need to capture user signature in my application and save it into sdcard for later use. I'am using the following code http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html to draw my signature. And when i save my signature it is getting saved along the background screen. I just need to save only signature part. How do i save the signture image without any background.  Could you please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep Background none...if this is not work go with SurfaceView following link
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html